# Почему результат сравнения строк неправильный?

Tags: java

Сравниваю так:

```
String s = "-123";
Boolean y = false;
if ("-".equals(s.charAt(0))){
    y = true;
}
```

Результат: y=false

Почему?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что Вы сравниваете разные типы.

Метод `charAt(...)` возвращает значение типа `char`, которое автоупаковывается в объектный `Character` и Вы этот объект сравниваете со объектом типа `String`, в результате несовпадения типов Вы и получаете такой результат.

Посмотрите исходный код метода `String.equals(...)`:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = value.length;
        if (n == anotherString.value.length) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = 0;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i] != v2[i])
                    return false;
                i++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Первое условие ложно, второе – **тоже ложно**, в результате метод возвращает `false`.

Добиться желаемого поведения, можно, например, так:

```
if ("-".equals(String.valueOf(s.charAt(0)))){
    y = true;
}
```

**UPD**:

> Мне нужно узнать, есть ли в строке определенный символ?

```
String s = "123";
char c = '2';
boolean contains = s.contains(String.valueOf(c));
```

или так:

```
String s = "123";
String c = "2";
boolean contains = s.contains(c);
```

Comment: А как правильно сравнить? Мне нужно узнать, есть ли в строке определенный символ?

Comment: @kaaa, Смотрите **UPD**.

Comment: Спасибо! Второй вопрос я задал некорректно. Мне надо было узнать есть ли в строке определенный символ на определенном месте. Но ответ вы дали еще в первый раз.

Comment: Я просто оставлю это здесь. Вдруг пригодится, но есть еще метод `s.indexOf('-')`, который вернет позицию символа в строке

Answer (score 4):

Метод `.charAt()` ожидаемо возвращает не `String`, а `char`, который упаковывается (boxing) в класс `Character`. `Character` сам по себе не равен строке, даже если строка состоит из одного этого символа - это было бы неверно даже семантически, потому что строка, например, реализует интерфейс `CharSequence`.